# Exibindo dados do usuário autenticado na view

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel, laravel-blade

Estou com um problema que acredito ser bem simples...
Preciso mostrar o nome do usuário logado nas minhas views...
como faço isso?

essa é uma das views

```php
@extends('layouts.template')

@section('body')

<h3>List_Lists</h3>
<p>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('list/create') }}">Adicionar Lista</a> <br />
</p>

<ul style="list-style:none;">
    @foreach($lists as $lista)
        <li class="task">
            <a href="{{ URL::to('list') }}/{{ $lista->id }}">{{ $lista->titulo }}
            ({{ count( $lista->tasks ) }} Tasks)</a> <br />
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@stop
```

Comment: Sugiro trocar o título da pergunta por algo que defina melhor o problema. Para ajudar na busca de outras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 8):

```
{{ Auth::user()->nome }}
```

Ou no lugar da propriedade nome, a que você necessitar utilizar.

Comment: @henrique - Adicione uma nova pergunta, assim não misturamos os problemas, favor adicionar além da tag Laravel, a tag blade

Comment: obrigado Flavio ..... e Blz Hernandes....   mais pra não sair do assunto eu não consigo entender eu crio um Model com os relacionamentos, um Controller inserindo ou buscando dados em um bd e uma View para exibir os resultados... mas seu eu quiser exibir os resultados de Varias tabelas do meu bd em uma mesma view se eu tenho um return View::make() me retornando consultas de apenas uma tabela ??? ex: view Index.blade eu mostro usuario logadotabela(usuario), ultimas novidades(tabela novidades), produtos destaque(tabela produtos)......     obs.: tomara que de pra entender ... hehe

Answer (score 4):

Na sua View vc já terá:

```php
{{ Auth::user()->nome }}
```

para exibir o nome do usuário Logado.

Você pode passar múltiplas variáveis para sua view:

```php
$produtos  = Produtos::all();
$novidades = Novidades::all();
View::make('index', compact("novidades","produtos") )
```

Comment: eu estava fazendo quase isso .. hehehe... fazia uma consulta , armazenava em uma variavel mas não conseguia passa pra view por causa que faltava o compact("var")....  vlw Flávio...  vc hoje salvou minha vida pra caramba viu... hehhe